# Like-box doesn't show wall pictures

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like, image

I have 661 people on my page, but only one appears on my wall.
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set OpenGraphs for your pages.

Then facebook will know which image to set as a thumbnail, title and description.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

this is an example of an [OpenGraph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)